# Python class <__main__.Credit at 0x> question

Tags: python, class

I'm practicing python class inheritance. But I find something weird. When I inherit the parent class and try to check the attribute. I cannot access the first attribute and it always returns the memory location. I cannot figure out what happened behind it. Hope to seek some help. Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
class Account():
def __init__(self, acct_num, open_deposit=100, overdraft_limit=1000, interest_rate=1):
    self.number = acct_num
    self.balance = open_deposit
    self.limit = overdraft_limit
    self.interest = interest_rate

def __str__(self):
    return f'The balance is {self.balance:.2f}'

def check_balance(self):
    print(self.balance)

def deposit(self, dep_num):
    self.balance += dep_num

def withdraw(self, wd_num):
    if self.balance + self.limit >= wd_num:
        self.balance -= wd_num
    else:
        return 'Your balance is insufficient'

def add_interest(self):
    self.balance *= (1 + (self.interest / 100))

class Credit(Account):
def __init__(self, withdrawl_rate=5):
    self.wth_rate = withdrawl_rate
    super().__init__(self)
    # super().__init__(self, open_deposit, overdraft_limit, interest_rate)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Credit Account: # {self.number} \nBalance: {Account.__str__(self)}'

def withdraw(self, wd_num):
    total_amount = wd_num * (1 + (self.wth_rate / 100))
    Account.withdraw(self, total_amount)

def change_limit(self, limit):
    self.limit = limit


x = Credit()
x.number
Out[]: <__main__.Credit at 0x109c13250>
```

Other attributes work well:

```
x.wth_rate
Out[]: 5
x.balance
Out[]: 100
x.add_interest()
x.balance
Out[]: 101.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `self` to the `__init__` function if the base class, which already gets by default `self`, like other instance functions.

So the `self` you're passing is the first argument for the base class `init`, which is `acct_num`, so it will just cotain a pointer to the instance.

You need to call `super().__init__(acct_num=SOME_VALUE)` for example to get the desired behavior.